# Independent Exponential Functions

Tags: independence

***Could anyone please be able to help me with the following question:***

We have 
$
\ f_{x} (x) = e^{λ} \
$ 
and 
$
\ f_{y} (y) = e^{α} \
$

If the joint PDF is equal to:
$\>$ $\>$ $\>$ $\>$
$
\ f_{xy} (x,y) = e^{λα} \
$

Then:

$\>$ $\>$ $\>$ $\>$ $
\ X \
$
and
$
\ Y \
$:
$\>$ $\square$ **are** independent ?

$\>$ $\>$ $\>$ $\>$ $\>$ $\>$ $\>$ $\>$ $\>$ $\>$ $\>$ $\>$  $\>$ $\>$ $\>$ $\>$ $\>$ $\square$ **must** be independent?

$\>$ $\>$ $\>$ $\>$ $\>$ $\>$ $\>$ $\>$ $\>$ $\>$ $\>$ $\>$  $\>$ $\>$ $\>$ $\>$ $\>$ $\square$ **could** be independent?

$\>$ $\>$ $\>$ $\>$ $\>$ $\>$ $\>$ $\>$ $\>$ $\>$ $\>$ $\>$  $\>$ $\>$ $\>$ $\>$ $\>$ $\square$ **cannot** be independent?

Comment: Please wrap $X$ and $Y$ with `$` as they are math variables.

Comment: could is the best option among the 4.. You can't assert anything for sure with this much info.. but could, yeah.. could goes with everything! Cheers!

Comment: The definition of $f_{xy}$ does not make sense. A positive constant is not a density function. Do you mean that $f_{xy}$ is exponential with parameter $\lambda \alpha$?.

Comment: They really ask if the **PDFs** are independent? This makes no sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**could**, because we don't know how the experiment where they come from work. They could be independent and they could be not, we dont have any information about that.